# How can I display span id data multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need a really simple solution to the following problem. I can get the JSON data and parse it just fine. To write it to the screen I'm using span id because it was in my example. Obviously when I try to use it a second time on the page it's now `null`. I'm not trying to instantiate a value, I'm trying to just call the data. I've tried using it as a class but nothing shows up. How can I simply modify this so I can pull the data multiple times on a page? For instance, I'm trying to display the state information multiple times on the page but it only shows once.  Can you help?

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Geo City Locator</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
<body> 
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span></div>
        <script>
          $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
             .done (function(location) {
                $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                $('#state').html(location.state);
                $('#city').html(location.city);
                $('#postal').html(location.postal);
                $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
             });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well you either add different ids or you add classes and you have to target it somehow.

Comment: First, you should not have multiple elements with the same ID; use a class instead. Second, the returned JSON has `city` and `state` set to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change from `id` to `class` since only one element can have the same ID on the same page. Then change the jQuery selector from `$('#state')` to `$('.state')` since we are using classes now.

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Geo City Locator</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
<body> 
    <div>State: <span class="state"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span class="state"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span class="state"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span class="state"></span></div>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
    <div>IP: <span id="ip"></span></div>
        <script>
          $.getJSON('https://geolocation-db.com/json/')
             .done (function(location) {
                $('#country').html(location.country_name);
                $('.state').html(location.state);
                $('#city').html(location.city);
                $('#postal').html(location.postal);
                $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                $('#ip').html(location.IPv4);
             });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's all I needed was to change the # to ".".  Ugh, sometimes the simplest things....   If you're ever in Florida look me up and I'll buy you a beer.